# Multiple routes on map for same source and destination point

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to add multiple routes on map with the same source and destination point. But by using google map i get only one route. can anyone give me reference or any sample code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share what you have tried till now?